# Angular 5 Validate Control with Dynamic Name

Tags: angular, validation, dynamic, controls

I thought this would be simple. I have the following chunk of HTML working as expected:

```
<label class="mb-0 form-label">
    Doc Part
</label>
<input type="number" name="DocPart" #DocPart="ngModel" class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="docSetting.DocPart" required/>
<div [hidden]="DocPart.valid || DocPart.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
    This field is required
</div>
```

The above is pretty simple, the required message shows when the control is dirty and empty. Now I have forms where the name of the control must be dynamic like this:

```
<label class="mb-0 form-label">
    Doc Part
</label>
<input type="number" name="DocPart{{j}}" class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="docSetting.DocPart" required/>
<div hidden="DocPart{{j}}.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
    This field is required
</div>
```

This doesn't work. The required message never shows. There must be a simple way to access a dynamically named control like this. How?

In the code above, docSetting is an object in a ngFor loop. DocPart is one of the properties on that object.

Comment: In the second version, Angular will check `valid` flag only once. Consider using array `DocPart[j]`.

Comment: In the code above, docSetting is an object in a ngFor loop. DocPart is one of the properties on that object, so I can't use an array like that here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, because `*ngFor` creates a 'scope' for the template variable:

```
<label class="mb-0 form-label">
    Doc Part
</label>
<input type="number" name="DocPart{{j}}" #myInput="ngModel" class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="docSetting.DocPart" required/>
<div hidden="myInput.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
    This field is required
</div>
```

You have your unique name, but `#myInput` can be the same.

Comment: Perfect, I knew there had to be a simple way. Thanks.

Comment: Its is not working if we have a *ngFor inside another *ngFor